# How to create different output with one input statement in a for loop?

Tags: python

I am wondering how to create different output with one input statement in a for loop (see my code below). For instance, how should I make each input statement read `Enter number 1:`, `Enter number 2:` and so on. Should I have only one input statement or multiple?

```
times = int(input("Enter how many numbers you want to sum"))

sum = 0

for i in range(0, times):
    numInput = int(input("Enter number"))
    sum = sum + numInput
print("The total is", sum)
```

Comment: `int(input("Enter number {}".format(i+1)))` ?

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you. What is that tool you used called?

Comment: tool? that's python `str.format`

Comment: I am learning python right now and so far I have not learned how to use format in an input statement yet. In print statements, yes, but not in input statements.That is why I am asking.

Comment: Don't put information in an image off-site. Manually add it to the question if it is relevant, otherwise, remove it. Especially if the information behind the link disappeared, then your question will become incomplete for later users.

Comment: Okay. My apologies as I am new to this website.

Comment: @afg229 Have you visited [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or read some of the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? These can help you learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One input is enough because you can change the string in your input prompt like this:

```
times = int(input("Enter how many numbers you want to sum? "))
sum = 0

for i in range(1, times+1):
    numInput = int(input("Enter number {}:".format(i)))
    # or use below code:
    # numInput = int(input("Enter number %d:" % (i)))
    sum = sum + numInput

print("The total is", sum)
```

To learn more about ***formatting python strings*** please refer to this link: 
https://pyformat.info/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `%` instead of `str.format` or f-strings for this code/ But for teaching rank novices, I'd usually go the other way, just because teaching `%` means they tend to run into the single-tuple-argument quirk before they've learned enough to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I changed the answer also added a link for more information